# Install 'locales' on alpine (node:8-latest) Docker image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use alpine (nodeJS) docker image, but I do get the error `/bin/sh: apt-get: not found`. So what would be the equivalent commands for doing this in alpine?

```
FROM node:8.6-alpine
ARG APP_LOCALE=en_US
ARG APP_CHARSET=UTF-8

RUN apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen ${APP_LOCALE}
RUN localedef ${APP_LOCALE}.${APP_CHARSET} -i ${APP_LOCALE} -f ${APP_CHARSET}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: localedef belongs to glibc, alpine use musl, which seems does not have a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Alpine linux uses another package manager.
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management

Comment: Thanks. I mean what is the equivalent command for that in alpine...? instead using debian...